# Connect to a Spring and Hibernate service using GWT

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt

I am trying to set up an environment with GWT, Spring, Hibernate, and MySQL. I got GWT and spring to set up to make RPCs to the server and return a message. But I am having some trouble connecting to the database. There is a service already set up to connect to database to retrieve data, but I am trying to connect to that service to retrieve data. So here's a general layout:

MyService -> UserService -> Database

I am getting the following error during execution.

00:00:00.003 [WARN] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mobiquitousUserService' defined in file [C:\Users\Yan\Desktop\Project\Workspace\MobiquitousPresentation\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\mobiquitous\presentation\server\MobiquitousUserSerivceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.mobiquitous.data.services.common.UserService]: : No matching bean of type [com.mobiquitous.data.services.common.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userService)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mobiquitous.data.services.common.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userService)}:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mobiquitous.data.services.common.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userService)}     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:914)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:783)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:784)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:711)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:194)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:993)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:897)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:463)     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:667)   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)

Could someone please give me some idea of what it means?

Comment: Please provide your Spring configurations and parts of code in UserServiceImpl that use @Qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the UserService that you are trying to inject in mobiquitousUserService constructor is not declared in your Spring context

Ensure you have annotated UserService with

```
org.springframework.stereotype.Service
```

annotation and that your Spring config is setup with

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: should the <context:annotation-config /> be associated with the UserService? Or should it be associated with MobiquitousUserService which call the UserService?

Comment: <context:annotation-config /> should simply be defined in your Spring context.

See
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config